# Express.js body parser middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Sorry for the poor title; I couldn't think of a succinct way to describe my problem.

I've got an Express server like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

// location (a)

app.use(function(req, res){
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://example.net' });
});

app.listen(5050, function(){
    console.log("listening on port 5050")
});
```

What I'd like to do is inspect the request body and, depending on the contents, continue through to `next()` or handle the request right away. Something like:

```
// insert at location (a)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.foo) {
        return next();
    }
    res.json({"ok": true, "data": "test data"});
});
```

If I simply insert the `body-parser.json()` middleware, though, it consumes the input stream, and there's no data available for the proxy request, which causes the request to hang forever waiting for data.

I know I could probably ditch the `http-proxy` library and write my own proxying code, but this code is a quick test for something else. **Is there a more elegant way for me to inspect the request body *and* have it passed along to the proxy?**

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, one of the troubles you are going to have is buffering the data long enough to inspect it before passing it off to the proxy middleware.  Is your request body particularly large?

Comment: More info on why body-parser doesn't play well with http-proxy: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/180#issuecomment-3996256 > "The bodyParser middleware is adding listeners for the 'data' and 'end' events to the request object but they are never removed. So when re-emitted by the buffer, they're picked up a second time by the bodyParser."

Comment: [A solution mentioned](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/180#issuecomment-12244852): [connect-restreamer](https://github.com/dominictarr/connect-restreamer) >Connect's bodyParser has a problem when using it with a proxy. It gobbles up all the body events, so that the proxy doesn't see anything!
**`connect-restreamer`** comes to the rescue by re-emitting the body to the proxy.